# Automatizacion con selenium 4.8 en pycharm

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estoy intentando automatizar un proceso bastante manual y hay un punto en el cual no he podido avanzar porque al hacer el click sobre el selector este no funciona(no avanza). Sin embargo si hago el click manualmente funciona correctamente.

Dejo parte del codigo para ver si me pueden ayudar:

Al inspeccionar el elemento que quiero hacer click:

```
<img src="/Resources/Prueba/selectRow.png" id="vSELECTEMPID_ACTION_0001" alt="Select Emp Id" title="Seleccionar 3 SOLES S.R.L. " class="Image_Action" style=";width: 25px" onfocus="gx.evt.onfocus(this, 41,'',false,'',40)" tabindex="0" data-gx-evt-control="vSELECTEMPID_ACTION" data-gx-evt="" data-gx-context="[&quot;&quot;,false]">
```

```html
<tr id="GridempresaContainerRow_0001" data-gxrendering_row="" data-gxrow="0001" class="Grid_WorkWithOdd"><td class="gx-tab-padding-fix-0 gx-attribute" data-cell-valign="middle" data-colindex="0" style="width:25px;text-align:left;"><img src="/Resources/prueba/selectRow.png" id="vSELECTEMPID_ACTION_0001" alt="Select Emp Id" title="Seleccionar 3 SOl" class="Image_Action" style=";width: 25px" onfocus="gx.evt.onfocus(this, 41,'',false,'',40)" tabindex="0" data-gx-evt-control="vSELECTEMPID_ACTION" data-gx-evt="" data-gx-context="[&quot;&quot;,false]"></td><td class="gx-tab-padding-fix-0 gx-attribute K2BToolsGridColumn" data-cell-valign="middle" data-colindex="1" style="text-align:right;"><span onchange="gx.num.valid_integer( this,'.');;gx.evt.onchange(this, event)" class="ReadonlyAttribute_Grid" data-gx-readonly="" id="span_vEMPID_0001" data-gx-enabled-id="vEMPID_0001">1</span></td><td class="gx-tab-padding-fix-0 gx-attribute K2BToolsGridColumn" data-cell-valign="middle" data-colindex="2" style="text-align:left;"><span onchange=";gx.evt.onchange(this, event)" class="ReadonlyAttribute_Grid" data-gx-readonly="" id="span_vEMPIDTA_0001" data-gx-enabled-id="vEMPIDTA_0001">Len</span></td><td class="gx-tab-padding-fix-0 gx-attribute K2BToolsGridColumn" data-cell-valign="middle" data-colindex="3" style="text-align:right;"><span onchange="gx.num.valid_integer( this,'.');;gx.evt.onchange(this, event)" class="ReadonlyAttribute_Grid" data-gx-readonly="" id="span_vEMPIDVSS_0001" data-gx-enabled-id="vEMPIDVSS_0001">3887</span></td><td class="gx-tab-padding-fix-0 gx-attribute K2BToolsGridColumn" data-cell-valign="middle" data-colindex="4" style="text-align:left;"><span onchange=";gx.evt.onchange(this, event)" class="ReadonlyAttribute_Grid" data-gx-readonly="" id="span_vEMPIDSLX_0001" data-gx-enabled-id="vEMPIDSLX_0001"></span></td><td class="gx-tab-padding-fix-0 gx-attribute K2BToolsGridColumn" data-cell-valign="middle" data-colindex="5" style="text-align:left;"><span onchange=";gx.evt.onchange(this, event)" class="ReadonlyAttribute_Grid" data-gx-readonly="" id="span_vEMPRAZONSOCIAL_0001" data-gx-enabled-id="vEMPRAZONSOCIAL_0001">3</span></td><td class="gx-tab-padding-fix-0 gx-attribute K2BToolsGridColumn" data-cell-valign="middle" data-colindex="6" style="text-align:left;"><span onchange=";gx.evt.onchange(this, event)" class="ReadonlyAttribute_Grid" data-gx-readonly="" id="span_vEMPNOMBRE_0001" data-gx-enabled-id="vEMPNOMBRE_0001">Le &amp; Com- 33</span></td><td class="gx-tab-padding-fix-0 gx-attribute K2BToolsGridColumn" data-cell-valign="middle" data-colindex="7" style="text-align:left;"><span onchange=";gx.evt.onchange(this, event)" class="ReadonlyAttribute_Grid" data-gx-readonly="" id="span_vEMPRUT_0001" data-gx-enabled-id="vEMPRUT_0001">20015252</span></td><td class="gx-tab-padding-fix-0 gx-attribute K2BToolsGridColumn" data-cell-valign="middle" data-colindex="8" style="text-align:left;"><span onchange=";gx.evt.onchange(this, event)" class="ReadonlyAttribute_Grid" data-gx-readonly="" id="span_vEMPDIRECCION_0001" data-gx-enabled-id="vEMPDIRECCION_0001">ert 45</span></td><td class="gx-tab-padding-fix-0 gx-attribute K2BToolsGridColumn" data-cell-valign="middle" data-colindex="9" style="text-align:left;"><span onchange=";gx.evt.onchange(this, event)" class="ReadonlyAttribute_Grid" data-gx-readonly="" id="span_vEMPDPTONOMBRE_0001" data-gx-enabled-id="vEMPDPTONOMBRE_0001">Trein</span></td><td class="gx-tab-padding-fix-0 gx-attribute K2BToolsGridColumn" data-cell-valign="middle" data-colindex="10" style="text-align:left;"><span onchange=";gx.evt.onchange(this, event)" class="ReadonlyAttribute_Grid" data-gx-readonly="" id="span_vEMPCIUDAD_0001" data-gx-enabled-id="vEMPCIUDAD_0001">Treiert</span></td></tr>
```

probé con el ID, con el XPATH, CLASS, CSS_SELECTOR y no funciona, lo que noté es que cuando hago el click manualmente, se crea un atributo llamado "data-gx-evt-inprogress="true"" que permite avanzar en la pagina.

Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agredeceria, no puedo mostrar la pagina porque es un sitio intranet.

Comment: Tendrás que mostrar un poco de código de lo que intentas realizar, sin eso nadie te podrá ayudar

Comment: Además de mostrar el código que intentas hacer, poco se puede hacer sin saber qué página estás _"automatizando"_ ya que lo normal hoy en día es que se manejen  eventos controlados por javascript. Selenium está pensado para _"testing"_, sobre todo para páginas que has creado tú y sabes cómo va a responder.